# Curve_fit error - IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Trying to fit a simplified Bloch-Grüneisen curve for resitivities. Not the best at Python so it's a little messy.

It all seems to work 'fine' up until curve_fit, where I get the error message:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as sc
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.constants as spc
import scipy as spy
Cu_2000A=np.genfromtxt('Cu_2000A.txt')
R = Cu_2000A[:,0]
T = Cu_2000A[:,1]

ylist = []   
def Bloch1(T,k,debye):
    for Tval in np.nditer(T):
        yval = float((k*(Tval/debye)**5))
        ylist.append(yval)

    return ylist
xlist = []
def Integrate(debye):
    for Tval in np.nditer(T):
        xval =(sc.quad(lambda x: ((x**5)/(((np.exp(x))-1)*(1-(np.exp(-x))))), 0, (debye/(Tval))))
        xlist.append(float(xval[0]))

    return xlist
def Bloch(T, R0, k, debye):
    test = np.asarray(Bloch1(T, k, debye))
    test2 = np.asarray(Integrate(debye))

    return (R0 + (test*test2))



popt, pcov = curve_fit(Bloch, T, R [0.1, 1000, 350])
```

Comment: Is this really the smallest example you can give? Can you find out what the input is that causes the problem, e.g. by placing the statement that fails in a try-except block and printing the input? Because right now, your question does not show a lot of effort of having tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Are you missing something between the `R` and the  `[0.1, 1000, 350]` in the call to `curve_fit`? Perhaps you want `curve_fit(Bloch, T, R, p0=[0.1, 1000, 350])`

Comment: p0 Seems to have fixed it! Thanks a bunch!

Thanks for the help, and apologies if its looked that way Energya, I haven't done a lot of python, so learning how to do all this has taken up most of the effort.